# Applying for two jobs in the same division in a company

Tags: job-search, applications

Yesterday I interviewed at a large company. The interview went OK, but I'd naturally like to continue my job search until I have a specific offer.

I have now found a new interesting position at the same company. This position shares some similarities with the first and it seems to me that, although the position is not in the same group as the one I interviewed for yesterday, there may be some collaboration between the two groups.

Would I insult either part by applying for this new position I have found? Or is it in any way considered bad practice to apply for this second job as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experiences I have applied for multiple positions in the same firm. But I usually check who the concerned HR Personal is who will be processing the application. If both the applications are being routed to the same person, I usually avoid a duplicate application till I receive a confirmation on the ongoing one. I have received interviews for jobs similar to the ones I have already applied as the HR noticed themselves that I have a matching profile for multiple vacancies.

So check who the contact person is and then decide. And even if they are in different groups as you told, they may still keep a central database for applicants. So I would suggest you apply anyway but inform that you are currently waiting for a feedback from a different group in the same firm. So in case they already have a result on the interview but maybe the final communication was pending to you, they can inform you accordingly and process the second application based on it.

Comment: I would say there is no harm in applying for both.  *However*, making personal contact about a position, rather than just sending in documents is always a good thing.  And they might have an opinion about how to handle it administratively.  So I agree with your suggestion of contacting them.